# Node.Js and MongoDB Compass connection error

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to MongoDB Compass.
I am using Typescript, Node.Js and Mongoose to connect however I am getting errors when trying to connect to it.

This is my mongo connection code

```
const url ='mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogApp';

mongoose.connect(url)
.then(() => {console.log("Connected to MongoDB")})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

 //*** BEEP BOOP ***//
 app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Your server available at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

My server starts normally and operates normally, however the connection to MongoDB gives me this massive error and I have no idea whats wrong with it.

```
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:819:32)
    at C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:377:10
    at C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1220:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:376:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\index.ts:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Filda\Desktop\Node.Js\InstaClone\backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1597:23) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code
```

I am using the same setup as on my other projects (I just coppied the code), but this time it doesn't connect.
My older projects use the same backend setup, this time I only rewrote it for typescript.

Comment: Have you started the `mongod` process? Also, check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Comment: Yes, its is running, I even tried connecting using the URL you get form the web, nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you even mongodb installed? When you connect from mongodb compass, what are you using as connection URL?

Comment: I am using this one like in the post 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogApp', It is the same URL I am using in my other projects, it just doesn't work in this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which verison of mongoose or mongoDB you are using, but you need to tell mongoose how to "look" for a connection so your code should look like this. I am not really sure how exactly it works, but you need to tell mongoose to look with IPv4 not IPv6 (Don't know why exactly)

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogApp';
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(url!, options)
.then(() => {console.log("Connected to MongoDB")})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));


 //*** BEEP BOOP ***//
 app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Your server available at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```